# Book suggestions

Tags: discussion

Is there a place on the Workplace.SE where we can get book suggestions? I am thinking of an example question at StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) in the C++ tag, which has a nice long list of good introductory/medium/advanced books; the "question" is locked (to indicate that this isn't a good question on the site normally; but does serve a purpose) and pinned to the top of the frequent tab so that newcomers can easily be directed to the appropriate place if necessary.

Would it be beneficial to do something similar on some of the Workplace.SE tags? E.g., have a locked question that contains a list of good books on workplace politics pinned to the frequent questions list on the [politics] tag?

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting question..

Comment: @Mods: would the question suggestion violate any SE Prime Directives? I can't imagine the network encouraging the use of locked questions to bypass rules on off-topic/subjective questions.

Comment: I like the idea of more useful tag wikis, but does anyone even really use them? You first need to click on the actual tag (instead of tagging your post with one) and then need to click on the "learn more" to actually reach the full wiki page.

Comment: @Lilienthal: Isn't that what historical locks are? Locks used on questions that are off-topic/subjective/some-other-close-reason but that mods wish to keep around? Granted, this wouldn't be a "historical" lock, but I think the principle is the same.

Comment: @R_Kapp [Not quite.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: If it's tag-specific, the tag wiki is a good place to put this information.  Historical locks are sometimes applied to questions that *turned out not to be* good questions; I'm not aware off-hand of a site that *set out to create an off-topic locked post from the start*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do we have a procedure for recommending good sources, or a place where we can store the links to these references?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2946/do-we-have-a-procedure-for-recommending-good-sources-or-a-place-where-we-can-st)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Lilienthal.

Tag wikis are a good way to include resources about the particular tag. Asking about books and resources in the main site defeats the purpose of SE, and would result in an epic fail of the **primarily opinion based** reason of closure.

Even if the questions are locked, it doesn't cover up the fact that the answers are opinion based.

Even if the question is framed like one of these, it is still off-topic:

1. Books on _______?  <--  Reason for closure: **Too broad**
2. Good books on _______?   <-- Reason for closure:  **Opinion based**

Comment: Here's an example from Stack Overflow of a comprehensive and (it appears) oft-cited tag wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info.

Comment: @MonicaCellio  Yeah, when the wikis can be crafted so nicely, there is no reason why questions need to ask for **good books** or **good resources.**    They definitely need [to be closed](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/8963/11097)